# OptaPlanner/TimeFold groupBy with list only ever has one element

Tags: optaplanner, timefold

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77228696/3791510).

I have two PlanningEntity classes like this:

```java
@PlanningEntity
class Location {
    private static long nextId = 0;    
    private long id = nextId++;

    @PlanningVariable
    Coordinates coordinates;
}

@PlanningEntity
class LocationList {
    private static long nextId = 0;    
    private long id = nextId++;

    @ShadowVariable(
            variableListenerClass = LocationListUpdatingVariableListener.class,
            sourceVariableName = "coordinates",
            sourceEntityClass = Location.class)
    List<Location> locations = ArrayList<>();
    int weight;
}
```

The solution class looks like this:

```java
@PlanningSolution
class Solution {
    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    List<Location> locations;

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    List<LocationList> locationLists;

    @ValueRangeProvider
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    List<Coordinates> possibleCoordinates;
}
```

The shadow variable updater looks like this:

```java
class LocationListUpdatingVariableListener implements VariableListener<Solution, Location> {

    @Override
    public void beforeEntityAdded(ScoreDirector<Solution> scoreDirector, Location location) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void afterEntityAdded(ScoreDirector<Solution> scoreDirector, Location location) {
        updateLocationLists(scoreDirector, location);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEntityRemoved(ScoreDirector<Solution> scoreDirector, Location location) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void afterEntityRemoved(ScoreDirector<Solution> scoreDirector, Location location) {
        updateLocationLists(scoreDirector, location);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeVariableChanged(ScoreDirector<Solution> scoreDirector, Location location) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void afterVariableChanged(ScoreDirector<Solution> scoreDirector, Location location) {
        updateLocationLists(scoreDirector, location);
    }
    
    protected void updateLocationLists(ScoreDirector<Solution> scoreDirector, Location location) {
        Solution solution = scoreDirector.getWorkingSolution();
        
        solution.locationLists.forEach(locationList -> {
            
            for(int i = 0; i < locationList.locations.size(); i++) {
                var locationListLocation = locationList.locations.get(i);
                
                if(locationListLocation.id == location.id) {
                    scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(locationList, "locations");
                    locationList.locations.set(i, location);
                    scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(locationList, "locations");
                }
            }
        });
        
    }
}
```

I have a constraint like this:

```java
Constraint myConstraint(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(LocationList.class)
           .filter(locationList -> locationList.locations.size() == 2)
           .join(Location.class)
           .filter((locationList, location) -> locationList.locations.contains(location))
           .groupby((locationList, location) -> locationList, ConstraintCollectors.toList((locationList, location) -> child))
           .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD, (locationList, locationsInList) -> weightedDistance(locationList.weight, locationsInList))
           .asConstraint("Shorter total distance is better");
}
```

The `weightedDistance` does something like add up all the distances between the assigned coordinates and multiplies by the weight. What it actually does is more complex, but the point is that it needs all the locations at once -- it can't be handled one at a time.

The part where I filter on 2 elements is not part of the actual constraint. I just put it in there to demonstrate the problem -- that the code makes it past there but somehow still only ends up with 1 location in `locationsInList`.

I can actually pull the locations out of `locationList` directly and it works, but I'm concerned that because `locationsInList` doesn't have the right locations in it that this won't be tracked correctly by the solver.

Comment: I suggest we approach it differently. Tell us the purpose of the constraint, explain what you're trying to accomplish, and maybe we can propose a solution with that goal in mind. Otherwise we're just randomly punching in the dark, getting more obscure constraint streams each time.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't say exactly what I'm doing, but I've updated the question with a lot more details that are analogous to what I'm doing. The real problem doesn't actually have locations, etc., but there is a notion of distance and other relationships between "locations" that we are checking with various constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was caused by a timefold bug: https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues/309

If I run without brute force everything works as expected.